# bellman equation mathmatics

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, reinforcement-learning

[image]

Can you help me understand this transformation??
I cannot understand this thing..

I heard that this is transformed by the law of total expectation
but I can't apply it.. help me please..

- I understand this formula.. but I can't understand what I asked.. [Deriving Bellman's Equation in Reinforcement Learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/243384/deriving-bellmans-equation-in-reinforcement-learning)

Comment: Can you reproduce the formula for $G_{t+1}$? This site supports math typesetting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference