# conditional expectation: an implication

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-expectation

$E[X|Y]$ is equal to the almost surely unique and deterministic function of
$Y$, say $\varphi (Y)$, such that

$$E[X f(Y)]= E[\varphi (Y)f(Y)]$$

for all bounded, measurable and non-negative $f$'s.

How can I **prove** this fact?

In particular, how the a.s. uniqueness and the equality of the conditional expectation to $\varphi(Y)$ follows from the definition of the conditional expectation defined as usual by $$E[X|Y]=\sum_x x\cdot P(X=x|Y)?$$

Comment: This definition of expectation is not one to use when you are considering a fact that might hold almost surely: you need a measure-theoretic definition.

Comment: @whuber what is wrong with the universal property at the top? Isn't that the measure theoretic definition (except for the fact that one can define it with or without test functions...)?

Comment: Caution: The definition is that $E[X|Y]$ is the almost $\sigma(Y)$-surely defined function that does some stuff. Let $A, B$ be two such functions, then integrate the test functions $\phi(\omega) = 1_{A > B}(\omega)$ and $\phi(\omega) = 1_{B > A}(\omega)$ multiplied by $A-B$. Then use that if $\int f = 0$ and $f$ is positive then $f=0$ (almost surely for the correct sigma algebra)

Comment: @Fabian The problem lies in the definition of conditional expectation, which works only for variables of at most countable support.

Comment: @whuber ooh you were talking about the explicit way of writing E[X|Y]... now I understand.

Comment: Concerning the second point (the explicit way of writing $E[X|Y]$). First of all, this can only be senseful if the space $X$ maps to is discrete (otherwise we need an integral instead of a sum). The only proof I have ever seen is quite complicated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97422/probability-distribution-of-functions-of-random-variables

Comment: I do not understand: for me the first part IS the definition of the conditional expectation...

Comment: @Xi'an For me only the last but one line in my original question IS the definition of a discrete conditional expectation.

Comment: @user852508: I corrected a typo in your question two days ago, namely that $\varphi(X)$ should be $\varphi(Y)$ and find the typo back. Could you please fix this typo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the discrete case, when both state spaces $\mathfrak X$ and $\mathfrak Y$ are finite or countable, the notion of *almost sure* simplifies into sure and any function $f:\mathfrak Y\longmapsto f(\mathfrak Y)\subset\mathbb R$ is measurable wrt the counting measures.

Now, in the discrete case,
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Xf(Y)]&=\sum_{x\in\mathfrak X,\,y\in\mathfrak Y}xf(y)\mathbb P(X=x,Y=y)\\
&=\sum_{x\in\mathfrak X,\,y\in\mathfrak Y}xf(y)\mathbb P(X=x|Y=y)\mathbb P(Y=y)\\
&=\sum_{y\in\mathfrak Y}\underbrace{\left\{\sum_{x\in\mathfrak X}x\mathbb P(X=x|Y=y)\right\}}_{\stackrel{\text{(a)}}{=}\,\mathbb E[X|Y=y]}f(y)\mathbb P(Y=y)\\
&=\sum_{y\in\mathfrak Y} \mathbb E[X|Y=y] f(y)\mathbb P(Y=y)\\
&= \mathbb E\{\mathbb E[X|Y] f(Y)\}
\end{align}
where equality (a) is using the standard definition of the conditional expectation in the discrete case. This is essentially [the proof of the Law of Total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Proof_in_the_finite_and_countable_cases) with an extra $f(Y)$. And this means that $\mathbb E[Xf(Y)]$ can be written as a particular $\mathbb E[\varphi^0(Y)f(Y)]$, when$$\varphi^0(y)=\mathbb E[X|Y=y]$$

Conversely, if there exists a function $\varphi:\mathfrak Y\longmapsto \text{conv}(\mathfrak X)$ *[where $\text{conv}(\mathfrak X)$ denotes the convex envelope of $\mathfrak X$ in order to include all possible combinations of the elements of $\mathfrak X$]* such that
$$\mathbb E[Xf(Y)] = \mathbb E[\varphi(Y)f(Y)]\tag{1}$$
for *every* real function $f:\mathfrak Y\longmapsto\mathbb R$, (1) applies to the indicator function $$f_\xi(y)=\mathbb I_{y=\xi}=
\begin{cases}1 &\text{ if }y=\xi\\0 &\text{ if }y\ne\xi\\
\end{cases}$$ for *every* $\xi\in\mathfrak Y$. This leads to
$$\mathbb E[X\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]=\underbrace{\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]}_{\stackrel{\text{(b)}}{=}\,
\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]\mathbb P(Y=\xi)}$$
being equal by (1) to
$$\underbrace{\mathbb E[\varphi(\xi)\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]}_{\stackrel{\text{(c)}}{=}\,\varphi(\xi)\mathbb P(Y=\xi)}$$
where both (b) and (c) are explained by the fact that
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y]\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]=\mathbb E[\underbrace{\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]}_{\text{constant}}\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]=\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]\times\mathbb E[\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]$$
and
$$\mathbb E[\varphi(Y)\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]=\mathbb E[\varphi(\xi)\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]=\varphi(\xi)\times\mathbb E[\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]$$
Hence to$$\varphi(\xi)=\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]$$for all $\xi$'s such that $\mathbb P(Y=\xi)>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but you are too fast for me. What does it follow for my purposes from this:$$=\sum_{y\in\mathfrak Y}\underbrace{\left\{\sum_{x\in\mathfrak X}x\mathbb P(X=x|Y=y)\right\}}_{\mathbb E[X|Y=y]}f(y)\mathbb P(Y=y)$$ (i.e. how do I obtain from this the r.h.s. $\mathbb{E}[\varphi(Y)f(Y)]$ from my OQ) and what does $\text{conv}(\mathfrak X)$ mean ?

Comment: Also, how do follow these equalities: $$\mathbb E[X\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]=\underbrace{\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]}_{=
\mathbb E[X|Y=\xi]\mathbb P(Y=\xi)}=\underbrace{\mathbb E[\varphi(\xi)\mathbb I_{Y=\xi}]}_{=\varphi(\xi)\mathbb P(Y=\xi)}$$

Comment: Please, how is defined $$f_{\xi}(y)={\mathbb I}_{Y=\xi}$$ ?